# Aggregate via Spring MongoTemplate to get max value of a collection

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-mongodb

I want to find users by most recent date (Assume the `User` object has a `date` field). The data is stored in MongoDB and accessed via a Spring `MongoTemplate.`

Example of the raw data:

```
{userId:1, date:10}
{userId:1, date:20}
{userId:2, date:50}
{userId:2, date:10}
{userId:3, date:10}
{userId:3, date:30}
```

The query should return

```
 {{userId:1, date:20}, {userId:2, date:50}, {userId:3, date:30}}
```

The aggregation method Ï am using is

```
db.table1.aggregate({$group:{'_id':'$userId', 'max':{$max:'$date'}}}, 
{$sort:{'max':1}}).result
```

Comment: In your expected results, you have two entries for userId 3 - is this intentional?  Also, the aggregate you use would sort the results by date, but your expected results are sorted by ID - which one do you want?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could Sort it first by date DESC and select the first while grouping by userID

```
final Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
    Aggregation.sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "date"),
    Aggregation.group("userId").first("date").as("Date")
);

final AggregationResults<User> results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "user", User.class);
```

Comment: the newAggregation is a static factory method to which we pass a list of aggregation operations.